# Set dialog field value as selected text

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog, ckeditor

I want to code CKEditor plugin. I have added button on panel and when I press it dialog is shown. In this dialog I can set text and after OK pressed this text inserted to the editor.

But I want add functionality. When I select text in editor and press this button I want see selected text in that dialog field. And after editing and press Ok selected text must be replaced with new one.

Thanks!

Comment: Cool I will write a basic dialog, be back in a few.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not 100% working, the first part is working, the final replacement isn't..

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'example',
{
    init: function( editor )
    {
        editor.addCommand( 'exampleDialog', new CKEDITOR.dialogCommand( 'exampleDialog' ) );

        editor.ui.addButton( 'example',
        {
            label: 'Insert a Link',
            command: 'exampleDialog'//,
            //icon: this.path + 'images/icon.png'
        } );

        CKEDITOR.dialog.add( 'exampleDialog', function( editor )
        {
            return {
                title : 'example Properties',
                minWidth : 400,
                minHeight : 200,
                contents :
                [
                    {
                        id : 'general',
                        label : 'Settings',
                        elements :
                        [
                            {
                                type : 'text',
                                id : 'mystring',
                                label : 'text',                             
                                commit : function( data )
                                {
                                    data.text = this.getValue();
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],

                onShow : function() {
                    //this._ranges = editor.getSelection().getRanges()
                    var mySelection = editor.getSelection().getSelectedText();
                    this.setValueOf("general","mystring",mySelection);

                },

                onOk : function()
                {
                    var data = {};
                    this.commitContent( data );
                    var txt = data.text;


                    editor.insertText(txt);  //this is not correct, since selection is being cleared...
                }
            };
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, works! Maybe you know how can I use language variables for multiple languages support in dialog?

Comment: Have you set up the language file? It would be something like: `editor.lang.example.title`

Answer (score 2):

My solution was to simply set it inide the onShow function:

```
    onShow: function () {
        this.setValueOf('my-tab-id', 'my-element-id', editor.getSelection().getSelectedText());

        // ...
    },
```

Full code skeleton:

```
(function () {
    CKEDITOR.dialog.add('mySelectorDialog', function (editor) {

        return {
            contents: [
                {
                    id: 'my-tab-id',
                    label: 'My Tab Label',
                    elements: [
                        {
                            id: 'my-element-id',
                            type: 'text',
                            label: 'My Element Label'
                        }
                        // ...
                    ]
                }
            ],

            onShow: function () {
                this.setValueOf('my-tab-id', 'my-element-id', editor.getSelection().getSelectedText());

                // ...
            },

            onOk: function () {
                // ...
            }

            // ...
        };
    });
})();
```